# Is graphene on a sticky tape strong enough to compete with my hand stretching it?

Tags: atoms, crystals, graphene, nanoscience, structure-formation

As we know we can make graphene using sticky tape so after we make graphene on a sticky tape will that thin sheet of graphene on a sticky tape be strong enough to compete with my hand trying to stretch and break apart the graphene? According to my observations that tape with a layer of graphene broke, then how we say that graphene is a very strong material?

Comment: Are you sure that you had a flawless single layer of graphene, or did you simply break the weaker tape in between separate regions of true graphene?

Comment: Very strong for its thickness is not the same thing as "so strong I can't break it". A spider's web is also "very strong".

Answer (score 0):

Graphene is also very thin. According to [this article](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2008/jul/17/graphene-has-record-breaking-strength) the force required to break a sheet of perfect graphene by pulling it apart in such a way that all bonds break at the same time is 42 N per meter. If the width of your tape is 1cm you would need to apply 0.42 N. It is not surprising that you were able to. Even if the sheet would be perfect, you would pull in a direction that would not require all bonds to break at once.

Comment: That last sentence is absolutely key for the general problem of strength of materials. When you pull on a ribbon, it is unlikely that the stress is distributed in a perfectly even manner. If there is a small imperfection in the material (like a surface crack) you get _stress concentration_ which results in stresses at the crack tip that are much greater than the mean stress. This is why it is easy to open a bag of chips at the "nick" that was put on the edge of the bag for that purpose.

Comment: @Floris and also others, why is graphene stronger than graphite when graphene is just a single layer while graphite is multiple layers so graphite must be stronger than graphene but it isn't why? Answer this question at http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/181245/74241